# Back button not functioning as expected in WebView - Android

Tags: java, android

I have 4 Fragments that displays news in main activity using view-pager and tabs. However my code works only for the first fragment ie tab 1

In main activity i have

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        if (mWebView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
        }
        else {

            super.onBackPressed();
        }

        return;
    }
```

So when back button is pressed, it hides web view there by taking user back to main layout. It works for tab 1

But in fragment 2,3,4 - when i press back button it exits the app. I use the same code as in fragment 1

I found out that - mWebView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE is not getting true - even though the web view is visible for fragment 2,3,4

Fragment 1 code :

```
public class WSJFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<News>> {


    .........


    public WSJFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsview, container, false);

        ............

        NewsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                // Find the current earthquake that was clicked on
                News currentNews = mAdapter.getItem(position);


                String newsUrl = currentNews.getUrl();

                progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                mWebView.loadUrl(newsUrl);

                mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        super.onPageFinished(mWebView, url);
                        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }

                });


            }


        });


        return rootView;
    }


    ........

}
```

https://github.com/mrafz/W3News

Comment: WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); should be like this WebView mWebView = (WebView) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.webview);

Comment: rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsview, container, false);

        mWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview); I have it like this. thats not the issue

Comment: Ok, but in OnBackPressed() your binding the Webview again, instead use globle variable

Comment: if i use global variable - and move  mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); to onCreate in mainactivity, app crashes when back button is pressed. null pointer

Comment: its working for tab 1.. so i dont know what is causing for other labs which use same logic

Comment: sorry I have make a mistake, Globle veriable will not work, because your WebView in Fragment and OnBackPressed in Activity, so it defiantly get null

Comment: but my question is how can it work for 1-tab? basically the object will be null.

Comment: I have a solution for this, but not sure its good practice or not

Comment: I made a interesting observation. in tab 2, after i click a news item- then it loads the page, then if i click tab 3 and come back to tab 2 and press back button, it works as expected

Comment: In your activity make global variable like this public static WebView mWebView , and in each fragment initialise like Activity_Name.mWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view); and in Activity OnBackPressed() use mWebView object

Comment: Its breaking app functionality. heres the full code if u like to take a look.  https://github.com/mrafz/W3News

Comment: k ill check it, and update

Comment: thanks.................

Comment: Hi I have updated your code

Answer (score 0):

I have checked in your code, make this changes.

**In MainActivity replace with this**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(mWebView != null){
        if (mWebView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
        }else {
            finish();
        }
    }else{ //if webview is null do something... here
    }
}
```

**In All 4 Fragments replace with this**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsview, container, false);

    MainActivity.mWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    MainActivity.mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

   //your remaining code here

 return rootView;
}
```

**And In each fragment where ever you find *"mWebView"* object replace it with *MainActivity.mWebView***

Comment: I was able to fix this by opening a new activity and passing the link to that activity and opening webview from there. I also figured why this is happening as android is creating multiple instances of webview in each of the 4 fragments. So it cannot always recognise which one from parent activity  onBackPressed(), so it takes the first one it finds. Even if you declare static, its the same because multiple insances are created and stored in one variable. So it cannot distinguish between 4 web-view instances